# cygwin & cygcheck

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin, dependencies

I want to know about cygcheck utility of cygwin. How can I use it to extract all the class hierarchy and dependencies with the help of cygwin?
Thanks !

P.S: Any tutorial that you can point out that shows how to use it for dependencies

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html

I found this document usefull some time ago